# Get reference from parent class to List.Count in child class

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have two classes A and B, B inheriting from A and additionally having a member of type `List<OtherObject>`.

Now I would need a reference to the `List.Count` property in `class A` reflecting changes that happen to the List in `class B` (removing/adding items). What's the best way to accomplish that, without changing the int member in `class A` by myself?

EDIT: OK, it is a little bit more complicate and I have some simplified code here for explanation: The int member myCount should hold the reference I was talking about.

```
public abstract class A{
protected int myCount;

    public void Process()
    {

        ProcessSpecificRequest();

        if(myCount == 0){
            //Do something
        }
    }

    protected abstract void ProcessSpecificRequest();

    }

public class B: A {
private List<Object> myList;

    protected override void ProcessSpecificRequest()
    {
    //Do something with the List

    }
```

}

Comment: It'd be easier to see what you're talking about with some code.

Comment: What is "the int member in class A"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A {
    public abstract int ListCount { get; }
}

class B : A {
    protected List<object> BList = new List<object>();
    public override int ListCount {
        get {
            return BList.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Pretty simple, I should have found this by myself :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class A, ICollection
{
    public abstract int Count { get; }
    //todo realize ICollection
}

public class B<T> : A
{
    protected List<T> OtherObject = new List<T>();
    public override int Count 
    {
        get
        {
            return OtherObject.Count;
        }
    }
    //todo realize ICollection
}
```